# How to get location in android 8.0?

Tags: android, notifications, location, android-8.0-oreo

I want to get the current location in longitude and latitude in Android 8.0+ when the app is running and I don't want to display notification as we have in the background services.

I was previously using background location services in android below 8.0 but in 8.0 we need to show a notification.

Answer (score 0):

Use job scheduler it will work in the idle state

```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= 21)
            {
                jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) (getActivity()).getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
                ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName((getActivity()), MyBackgroundService.class);
                JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
                        .setPeriodic(100).build();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Service started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
            }
```

MyBackgroundService.class

```
public class MyBackgroundService extends JobService {

private JobParameters params;
private myTask doThisTask;
boolean isGPSEnable = false;
boolean isNetworkEnable = false;
double latitude,longitude;
LocationManager locationManager;
Location location;
private String UserIDForToken;
private WeakReference<Context> cReference;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private LocationListener locationListener;
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager;


@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d("called","onStartJob");
    this.params = params;
    cReference = new WeakReference<Context>(MyBackgroundService.this);
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(cReference.get());
    doThisTask = new myTask();
    doThisTask.execute();
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    if (doThisTask != null)
        doThisTask.cancel(true);
    return false;
}

private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Log.d("called","doInBack");
        Log.d("called","done");

        /** displaying a toast ... **/
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("called","handle.post");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DONE !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fn_getlocation();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        //jobFinished(params, false);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}


@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void fn_getlocation(){
    Log.d("called","fn_getlocation");
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable){

    }else {


        if (isGPSEnable){
            location = null;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
            if (locationManager!=null){
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location!=null){
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
private void fn_update(Location location){
    if(haveNetwork()) {
      // do your job here
    }else if(!haveNetwork())
    {
       Log.d("network not there","what");
    }

}





private boolean haveNetwork(){
    boolean have_WIFI=false;
    boolean have_MOBILE_DATA= false;

    connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) cReference.get().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos= connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();


    for(NetworkInfo info:networkInfos)
    {
        if(info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if(info.isConnected())
                have_WIFI = true;
        if(info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if(info.isConnected())
                have_MOBILE_DATA = true;
    }
    return have_MOBILE_DATA || have_WIFI;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I assume the **notification** you meant is the dialog to prompt for location permission here.

To get user location in Android 8.0, you can use Google's **FusedLocationProviderClient**

Before that, you need to get location permission from user.
Follow the steps below:

**Add permission in your AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Request location from user**

```
//This can be any integer you want, just make sure they are same while requesting and handling the result
val REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE = 100

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@SplashActivity,
                    listOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).toTypedArray(),
                    1)
```

Override **onRequestPermissionsResult** function to capture the permission dialog result

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Permission Granted. Yeah!
            }else{
                //Permission Denied. You might need to show a dialog to let user understand why u need the location, or disable any features that need location
            }
        }
    }
```

**Implementing the library, add below line in app level gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

**Then, in the activity / fragment you want to get location,**

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
                .lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location->
                    Log.i("LocationLatitude",location.latitude.toString())
                    Log.i("LocationLongitude",location.longitude.toString())
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { error->
                    error.printStackTrace()
                }
```

You can actually declare **LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)** as a global variable or use data injection, if you want to use the location repeatedly in your application.

If you prefer shortcuts than the native way, you can look into libraries like [Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) or [EasyPermissions](https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions)

Comment: I am talking about notification you have to display like this app is using GPS in the notification drawer